# How do I make part of a regular expression optional in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

To match the following:

```
On Mar 3, 2011 11:05 AM, "mr person" 
wrote:
```

I have the following regular expression:

```
/(On.* (?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) \d{1,2}, [12]\d{3}.* at \d{1,2}:\d{1,2} (?:AM|PM),.*wrote:)/m
```

Is there a way to make the at optional? so if it's there great, if not, it still matches?

Comment: +1 negaging the -1, I just don't think its right is all, sorry...

Comment: @sln: Did you mean "negating"? Also, why do you feel the downvote is unjustified?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Sure. Put it in parentheses, put a question mark after it.  Include one of the spaces (since otherwise you'll be trying to match two spaces if the "at" is missing.) `(at )?` (or as someone else suggested, `(?:at )?` to avoid it being captured).

Answer (score 18):

Don't forget `(?:)` to make sure the bracketed expression doesn't get captured

```
(?:at)?
```

Comment: This works for complex expressions too e.g.  /(\w+(\[\w+\](?:\[\d+\])?)+)(?:\[\w+\])/;

Comment: I never knew how to make it not get captured when I used parens for optional items, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you just need to group the optional part...

```
   (at )*
```

And, ok, I guess that will match *at at at at*, so you might want to just do:

```
   (at )?
```

Comment: That should be a `?`, not an `*`.

Answer (score 2):

Others got your answer. This is just an aside re: Regular Expressions.

When you say "conditions" in regular expressions, it refers to the regex language. Like any language, its a branch in code execution, but the code is a different regular expression path, the "code" of regular expressions.

So in psudo code: if (evaluation is true) do this regular sub-expression, else do this other sub-expression.

This conditional exists in advanced regular expression engines ... Perl.
Perl uses the most advanced regular expression engine that exists. In version 6 and beyond it will be an integral part of the language, where code and expression intermingle seamlessly.

Perl 5.10 has this construct:
(?(condition)yes-pattern|no-pattern).

**Edit** Just a warning that where Perl goes, every other language follows as far as regular expression.

Comment: +1. I went ahead and edited the question to use "optional" instead.